# how to insert into in 2 table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

"Make a query that having all orders by employees from employeeUK in the orderUK table"

my table of employeeUK:

```
select *
into employeeUK
from Employees
where Country = 'UK'
```

then i want to make the orderUK table:

```
select *
into orderUKcoba
from Orders o join employeeUK e
where (e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID)
```

but what i got is

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

how to correct that?

Comment: You are missing an `ON` clause for your `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

> How to insert into in 2 table?

You could do that by using **[`OUTPUT Clause`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)** as the following:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable1(Column1, ...)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Column1, ... INTO TargetTable2
SELECT Column1, ...
FROM SourceTable;
```

Here is a simple example on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=041ed8cbc3f7e61c97252eb30e1d42a7)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax uses `ON`:

```
select *
into orderUKcoba
from Orders o join
     employeeUK e
     on e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID;
```

This will return an error, because at least one column is duplicated (`EmployeeId`) and tables cannot have duplicate column names.  But that is not the question you asked.

You should be listing out the columns explicitly for a new table.

Comment: but what i got is 'Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'EmployeeID' in table 'orderUKcoba' is specified more than once.'

Comment: @JessicaMaya . . . Read my answer.  That is *exactly* what I said would happen.  This answers the question that you asked.

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` requires `ON` clause :

```
select o.col, . . . , e.col, . . . -- Qualify all column names explicitly 
into orderUKcoba
from Orders o join 
     employeeUK e
     on e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: but what i got is "Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'EmployeeID' in table 'orderUKcoba' is specified more than once."

Comment: @JessicaMaya. . . `employeeoid` available in both table. So, use of both in `SELECT` doesn't make sense. So, use only one or re-name it using `as`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **ON** clause instead of WHERE clause while joining the table, please use below query

```
select *
into orderUKcoba
from Orders o join employeeUK e
on (e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID);
```